# Annoying unused variable popup

Tags: visual-studio-code

is there a way to remove or slightly move up the annoying "unused variable" popup, because it is displaying just above the cursor and the variable in question. This is annoying because it is often appearing just before I click the variable and so it takes the focus. This is often happening and is realy annoying.
Yes, I know the variable is unused yet, let me edit it please. ^^

- A sample function with an unused variable :

[image: A sample function with an unused variable]

- 1 second after I hover my mouse on the variable :

[image]

Comment: have you enabled semantic highlighting?, you can increase the hover /tooltip delay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Command Palette (⇧⌘P) with **Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)**, add the below snippet:

```
{
    "javascript.showUnused": false,
}
```

Save it and the "unused variable" popup should disappear from now on.

Alternatively, you can also delay the pop as rioV8 suggested in the comment. Instead of the above snippet, add this one:

```
{
    "editor.hover.delay": 3000
}
```

Then the popup will show up 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds) after you hover over the text.

Comment: Thanks ! I increased the delay since I still want to see when I have unused variables in my code. Life is better now haha